# ReportViewer - Dados mesclam colunas ao serem exportados para excel

Tags: .net, vb.net, microsoft-excel, visual-basic-6, reportviewer

Estou gerando um relatório e exportando para excel, utilizando ReportViewer e DataSet.

O ReportViewer consiste em uma tabela e dois `textbox`, que se referem ao título e empresa, e uma imagem. Após fazer alguns testes foi constatado que os `textbox` acima da tabela, um alinhado no canto esquerdo e o outro no direito, estão influenciando na mesclagem das células, que consequentemente afetam as colunas. Gostaria de um auxílio para fazer que o `textbox` alinhado a minha direita siga sempre o tamanho da primeira coluna e o da esquerda da última, para que não ocorra mais essa mesclagem. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Estou utilizando o ReportViewer no **VS 2008**.

Att,

Honan

O que devo configurar para corrigir este erro?

Answer (score -1):

Para evitar células mescladas em relatórios do SSRS exportados, temos que observar se o alinhamento da célula é igual com o Excel.

Podemos corrigir colocando os cabeçalhos e rodapés do Report alinhados com as colunas na área de detalhes.

O lado direito de um cabeçalho, rodapé ou outro objeto deve estar alinhado com o lado direito das colunas do relatório, o mesmo vale para a esquerda.

Espero te ajudado.